# Как организовать переход между View с сохранением данных?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, ios7

Я для тренировки сделал галерею:

[image]

Я хочу организовать открытие изображения на полный экран при клике. Открытие само я уже сделал, однако у меня возникла проблема: в первый раз всегда открывается изображение под индексом 0, а в следующий раз то изображение, на которое я кликал до этого. Код выглядит так:

```
   -(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
        selectedPhotoIndex = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"%li", selectedPhotoIndex);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fullAttachShow"]){
        DetailShowViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.fullImage = selectedPhotoIndex;
        NSLog(@"%li", (long)detailViewController.fullImage);
    }
}
```

Как я понял, у меня при клике вызывается метод: `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`
и лишь потом: `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

И получается, что в следующие разы у меня открывается та картинка, которая должна была открыться до этого.

Как мне сделать, чтобы при клике сначала срабатывал `-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` и лишь потом `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, у вас на каждой ячейке висит свой отдельный segue, в таком случае стоит удалить все сегвеи и добавить новый между контроллером галереи и контроллером, в котором открывается картинка. И изменить методы:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [collectionView selectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally];
        selectedPhotoIndex = indexPath.row;
    UIImage *image = self.images[indexPath.row];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DrawToDetail" sender:image];
    NSLog(@"%li", selectedPhotoIndex);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"fullAttachShow"]){
        DetailShowViewController *detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        detailViewController.fullImage = (UIImage*)sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, CollectionView не владеет информацией, какое изображение тыкалось. Он знает тольео id. Вот и мне надо передать id.  Я передаю id вот тут:

    detailViewController.fullImage = selectedPhotoIndex;

Comment: Тогда надо заменить detailViewController.fullImage = (UIImage*)sender; на
detailViewController.imageIndex = selectedPhotoIndex;

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо!